# automate a windows command line utility with a batch file - send keystrokes to std input after utility starts

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface

I have a command line utility which opens a serial connection specified by args sent in (duh) the command line.  After the utility starts, I can type into the std input to send strings to the port to which I am connected.  What I would like to do is start the utility with a batch file (easy enough), then automate the keystrokes I wish to send.  I am having no luck on my own and need some expert advice.

I'll give a more specific example:
I start teraterm.exe (opensource serial communication utility) in a batch file with this line:
"call serialterm com5 115200 ascii yes"
Then, I can type "Hello World " and receive the response from the open port.
I want the next line in my batch file to send "Hello World " for me, so that I can issue other string commands by listing them in the batch file.

Help is greatly appreciated!

-Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To automate this, a batch file is not the perfect solution(And I'm one of the batch fanatics), as it is not possible to send keystrokes.
You could switch to JScript/VBscript (possible to send keystrokes, but it's tricky and not very reliable).

But I would recommend a tool like AutoIt, as it can do such things very good.

Comment: indeed, not a perfect solution, but is there really no way to redirect input to a different process as you can in a Unix terminal?

Comment: You can redirect with the pipe `|`, but not to a program like TeraTerm. So I assume the only way will be the **SendKeys** with AutoIt or similar

Comment: Thanks for the info and recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

Put the commands in another file and use the < [redirection operator](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: But I didn't believe that this would work (with tera term), as it is nearly the same as a pipe