# controlling interactive console programs from batch file (cmd)

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have a WindowsXP console program that offers an interactive cli mode (some cisco tool) prompting for username and password. How can I programmatically pipe those in from a .bat file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will depend on the tool.

Hopefully the cisco tool supports command line parameters (`-username=foo` etc), can read commands from a pipe (`echo username | tool.exe`), or can accept an input file (`tool.exe @input.txt`).

If it gets all its input from stdin, you can create a text file containing the input in the right order and pipe it to the application.  For example, create a file `input.txt` with this content:

```
myusername
mypassword
```

and do this so tool.exe gets its input from input.txt:

```
tool.exe < input.txt
```

But once again it depends on the tool.

Failing those easy answers, the next option is sending keystrokes to the cmd window, using jscript, vbscript or some other language.  See [automate a windows command line utility with a batch file - send keystrokes to std input after utility starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722605/automate-a-windows-command-line-utility-with-a-batch-file-send-keystrokes-to-s).

Comment: `tool.exe < input.txt` is more efficient than `type input.txt | tool.exe`

Comment: You are correct, I needed to send keystrokes to the window, since the cisco tool tried to be "secure", meaning borderline unusable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems, but none of the listed solutions worked.
I tried different things and the following worked for me:

```
Command.exe "First Interactive choice" "Second one" "Third"
```

Comment: this answer helped me pass file to sqlite: `sqlite3.exe db.dat ".read query.sql"`